# Python ldap3 Search whenCreated

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to search AD for users created on specific dates and it is giving me all the users.  How can I filter?

```
def creating_date(self, when_Created = "2020-03-11", attribute="whenCreated"):        
    """
    Queries for users created on specific date
    """
    connection = self.conn

    attributes = ["cn",  
                  "displayName",
                  "mail",
                  "whenCreated"]

    search_filter = f"(&(objectClass=person))"
    connection.search(self.search_base, search_filter, attributes=attributes)

    entry = self.conn.entries

    try:
        return entry

    except (IndexError):
        return "{}"
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You must construct the search_filter to contain the `whenCreated` attribute and the `when_Created` value that was passed to the method.

Something like this:

```
ldapFilter = ldap.filter.escape_filter_chars(when_Created)
search_filter = f"(&(objectClass=person)(whenCreated=" + ldapFilter + "))"
```

Be aware that although you can just concatenate the `when_Created` value, using `escape_filter_chars()` prevents code injections.

**Edit:**

Just looked at one of my own scripts and it uses `ldap.filter.filter_format()` to construct the filter: https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/reference/ldap-filter.html#ldap.filter.filter_format